# Convert number into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

When I type a number with prompt `var myNumber = parseInt(prompt("..."))`I want it to be converted into an array of numbers. When I try with `myNumber = myNumber.split("")` it returns:

> Object 1 has no method 'split'

help me please

Comment: What are you using to delimit the numbers in the prompt?  You can't split a number, you split strings.

Comment: Why don't you convert to number after split?

Comment: I didn't know that i can't split() a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot split the int, you need to have a string data type for this code to work!

So, I would like to suggest to first split it and then convert it to int as

```
var numbers = "1, 2, 3";
var eachNumber = numbers.split(",");
/* now parse them or whatso ever */
```

This will work, as you're just splitting the string. And then you will parse it just the way you did it in the first method (of yours).

Comment: i should have thought about making another var where I split the firts var. thank you Afzaal!

Comment: yes, you could have done that! :) However, you're most welcome .. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var intArray = prompt("...").split(" ").map(Number);
```

Comment: You can shorten your `map` by simply writing `.map(Number)`, try it out

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the number to string, then split it.

You would then want to return it to an integer.

```
var myNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"));
var tempString = myNumber + "";
var arr = tempString.split("");
console.log(arr);
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/Wa5zD/

Answer (score 0):

`myNumber` is an integer variable, which does not hold **`.split()`** method, it belongs to string variable.

```
var no = "12 13 14 15";
var noV = no.split(" ")
```